# How to Adjust the Font Size of an Equation?

Tags: equations

I have an equation in a double column context. As can be seen from the picture below, the equation is just a little bit wider than a single column. I do not want to create a span-column equation for it. Is there a way I can change it to a smaller font size so it will fit in one column?

I am editing the file in LyX, so it would be great if there is a way to do it directly in Lyx. If not, LaTeX codes are also acceptable.

[image]

After changing to \bmatrix as suggested by @daleif, it look like
[image]

Can the space between the two matrices on the left hand side and the spaces between columns of the first matrix be further reduced?

Comment: You really should not, and if this is for example for a journal article, such things would be unacceptable for the journal style. Writing in a two column style is a big hassle. There are a few things  you can do here, use the bmatrix env for the matrices, don't do them by hand using array etc. This should reduce the spacing around the `[] `s, next break the line, here I'd probably wrap the inner contents in a gathered env and break the line (``\\``) before the =. I don't know if there are good interfaces for this in LyX (it is a rather limited writing environment)

Comment: please, be so kind and provide small, complete document (in LaTeX) which we can compile/modify that equation will fit one column. or the *daleif* comment already solved your problem?

Comment: This will need some more effort to fix, since the equation is quite a bit too wide. Observe that the equation is also labeled with (31) which also should go into the same line. So in addition to using `bmatrix` etc as suggested by @daleif consider to replace the N-vector by N (maybe in boldface or with some other vector marker), and likewise the zero vector by zero (maybe with a vector marker). As a last resort, use a smaller font (no matter whether the publisher deems this acceptable or not): contents and readability is more important than editor rules.

Comment: Thanks @daleif, changing from \array to \bmatrix solves the problem. I have added the appearance after the alteration in my question. Can you suggest if there is a way to further reduce the spacing between the two matrices on its left hand side? The spacing looks a little wide right now after the matrices themselves are tighter.

Comment: Did you change the image?

Comment: @daleif I just finished editing it. Please have a look.

Comment: @ gernot can you suggest a way to just make the font size of this equation smaller without changing the font size of other equations and the text body?

Comment: I would still break the line in two for better readability and overall compliance to the document style (inconsequent spacing looks bad). You could also accept it as it stands as it is no longer long get than the column. The placement of the (31) is a bit odd though, too close

Comment: @daleif Is it possible to move the (31) a little bit downwards?

Comment: `\raisetag{amount} ` should help. Exactly which document class is this. It is a bit strange that it does not place the eq no a bit lower.

Comment: @daleif It is IEEE transactions. Where do I put \raisetag? Before \end{equation}?

Comment: Should have guessed, they are a bit unusual. Look it up in amsmath manual, I'm not at pc at the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either reduce the value `\arraycolsep` and use the `fleqn` environment from `nccmath`, or use the `medsize` environment, also from `nccmath`, which reduces the font size to about 80 % of `\displaystyle`.

```
\documentclass{ieeetran}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

 \begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{fleqn}
  \begin{equation}
    \setlength{\arraycolsep}{3pt}
    \begin{bmatrix}
      -k_w + \sin α₁ & -k_w +1 & -k_w + \sin α₁ \\
      \sin 5α₁ & 1 & \sin 5α₁ \\
      \sin 7α₁ & -11 & \sin7α₁ \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \!
    \begin{bmatrix}
      N₁ \\ N₂ \\ N₃
    \end{bmatrix}
    =
    \begin{bmatrix}
      0 \\ 0 \\ 0
    \end{bmatrix}
  \end{equation}
\end{fleqn}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{equation}
  \begin{medsize}
    \begin{bmatrix}
      -k_w + \sin α₁ & -k_w +1 & -k_w + \sin α₁ \\
      \sin 5α₁ & 1 & \sin 5α₁ \\
      \sin 7α₁ & -11 & \sin7α₁ \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \!
    \begin{bmatrix}
      N₁ \\ N₂ \\ N₃
    \end{bmatrix}
    =
    \begin{bmatrix}
      0 \\ 0 \\ 0
    \end{bmatrix}
  \end{medsize}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The first one looks great for this particular equation while the second one works for some equations that are a little bit longer than a column width.

Comment: Hi @Bernard, when I was trying to cite the equation defined by the fleqn environment, it shows the section number (something like III-C) instead of the equation number. To properly cite the equation (1) in your answer above, where should I insert the equation label? I have tried to put the equation label before `\end{equation}` and other places, but it did not work.

Comment: If I place a label *inside* the `equation` environment (not between `fleqn` and `equation`), I have no problem.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the second picture in the question with

```
\documentclass[11pt]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{equation}{30} % to reproduce the example

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
  -k_w + \sin \alpha_1 & -k_w +1 & -k_w + \sin \alpha_1 \\
  \sin 5\alpha_1 & 1 & \sin 5\alpha_1 \\
  \sin 7\alpha_1 & -11 & \sin7\alpha_1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  N_1 \\ N_2 \\ N_3
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

I find it unacceptable that a big organization like IEEE still uses

```
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
```

and Computer Modern for math.

An immediate improvement can be obtained by doing `\usepackage{mathptmx}` together with a trick for pushing the equation far left and decreasing locally `\arraycolsep`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{equation}{30} % to reproduce the example

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation}
\addtolength{\arraycolsep}{-3pt}
\hfilneg
\begin{bmatrix}
  -k_w + \sin \alpha_1 & -k_w +1 & -k_w + \sin \alpha_1 \\
  \sin 5\alpha_1 & 1 & \sin 5\alpha_1 \\
  \sin 7\alpha_1 & -11 & \sin7\alpha_1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  N_1 \\ N_2 \\ N_3
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
\hspace{1000 pt minus 1fil}
\end{equation}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Better yet with

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

instead of `\usepackage{mathptmx}`:

[image]